# Split string and numbers

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to split this string `" "109491: Navy/Red115138: Navy/Light Grey"` in `Colour Code` and `colour name`. The numeric is colour-code and the string including `\` is color name. I have tried this regular expression `"(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)"` but it did not work as desired . Some times it is returning empty in `Colour Code`.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean - sometimes? For what input specifically?

Comment: kindly put the string that you want to split

Comment: Actually i am getting the above mentioned string from the webservice but i need to store the colour code and color name seperately for specific reason.

Comment: @SaddamAbuGhaida "109491: Navy/Red115138: Navy/Light Grey" this is the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
(?:(\d+):\s([^\d]+))+?
```

This will capture the numbers and text as separate captures.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Where does the screenshot you posted come from?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this:

```
(\d+[^\d]+)
```

It is "select numbers.. then anything else that isn't a number". So it matches like this:

```
109491: Navy/Red115138: Navy/Light Grey
|______________||______________________|
```

E.g:

```
var str = "109491: Navy/Red115138: Navy/Light Grey";
var matches = new List<string>();

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(str, @"(\d+[^\d]+)")) {
    matches.Add(match.Value);
}

// matches[0] = 109491: Navy/Red
// matches[1] = 115138: Navy/Light Grey
```