# Split string between numbers

Tags: r, string, split

Similar to the question uploaded here:
[Split string and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778674/split-string-and-numbers)
I have a string that contains both numbers and words, with the pattern of:

```
20.40title1. description1. 21.00title2. description2 ...
```

The final product that I would like to have is of the form

```
Hour   title   description
20.40  title1  description1
21.00  title2  description2
 ...    ...       ...
```

So I will probably need to split the sting before each appearance of a number and then split it again with the first appearance of "."
I'm having some trouble with the first step.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 4):

Since the separator is of zero width, it seems easier to think of this as an extraction or matching task rather than as a splitting task. For this approach you start by writing regular expressions to match each piece you want to extract. The `stringr::str_match` function is a convenient way to do it.

```
x <- "20.40title1. description1. 21.00title2. description2"

out <- do.call(
    cbind,
    str_match_all(
        x,
        c("\\d+\\.\\d+",
          "title\\d+",
          "description\\d+")))
```

If desired you can clean up and name the result;

```
out <- setNames(type.convert(as.data.frame(out)),
                c("Hour", "title", "description"))
out
##   Hour  title  description
## 1 20.4 title1 description1
## 2 21.0 title2 description2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(A=gsub('(description\\d)','\\1-',A)) %>% 
       separate_rows(A,sep='-') %>% 
       mutate(Hour=str_extract(A,'\\d{2}.\\d{2}'),Title=str_extract(A,'title\\d+'), Description=str_extract(A,'description\\d+')) %>% 
       filter(!is.na(Hour))

                            A  Hour  Title  Description
1   20.40title1. description1 20.40 title1 description1
2 . 21.00title2. description2 21.00 title2 description2
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text="
A
'20.40title1. description1. 21.00title2. description2'
",header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `strapply` from `gsubfn`

```
ss <- "20.40title1. description1. 21.00title2. description2"

library(gsubfn)
strapply(
    strsplit(ss, "\\s(?=\\d)", perl = T), "(\\d+\\.?\\d*)(\\w+)\\.*\\s+(\\w+)\\.*",
    c, combine = list, simplify = x ~ do.call(rbind, x))
#     [,1]    [,2]     [,3]
#[1,] "20.40" "title1" "description1"
#[2,] "21.00" "title2" "description2"
```